# Did I initialize my LSTM correct or do my states reset all the time?

Tags: python, pytorch, initialization, lstm

Currently looking to reset my model for every fold in a Cross Validation when I realized I might initialized my model all wrong. I am very confused right now because it looks like every forward pass in my model resets my hidden state and cell state to zeros. I think I added the init_hidden function when I went from only training with batch size =1 to different batch sizes.

Currently rethinking what I did the last week. Don't know if my model is working like this or not.

```
class Model_GRU_1(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_features, n_classes, n_hidden, n_layers,dropout):            
        super().__init__()
        self.gru = nn.GRU(
            input_size=n_features,
            hidden_size=n_hidden,
            num_layers=n_layers,
            batch_first=True,
            dropout=dropout,
            bidirectional=True
        )

        
        self.dense = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        weight = torch.zeros(n_layers,n_hidden)
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(weight)
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(weight)

        self.classifier = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_classes)


    def init_hidden(self):       
        hidden_state = torch.zeros(self.gru.num_layers,batch_size,self.gru.hidden_size)
        cell_state = torch.zeros(self.gru.num_layers,batch_size,self.gru.hidden_size)
        return (hidden_state, cell_state)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.hidden = self.init_hidden()
        _, (hidden) = self.gru(x)                  
        out=hidden[-1]
        out2 = self.dense(out)
        out3 = self.relu(out2)                                 
        return self.classifier(out3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently resetting your hidden states to zero on each batch, but you're not passing them to `self.gru.forward` which has optional `hx` argument. When it is `None`, [pytorch will initialize it for you](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b372be4211d40be92ffbb025cac0038ee3445141/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py#L932-L934) -- it is initialized to zero, so it would be the same as if you passed your hidden state on the first pass. If you're happy with your results using this model, you can just as easily remove anything relating to `self.hidden` including `init_hidden`.

Comment: I am really having trouble understanding this and everything around it to be honest. I would be really thankful if you could answer some of my questions.

1. Do the hidden states need to be initialized to 0 after every batch and if so why? Doesnt matter if I or pytorch does it, but is it necessary?

Comment: So my model is a timeseries classifier. Each sequence consists of 190 timestamps. So I thought I need to reset my hidden states after every sequence inside a batch. My thought process was that when I have batch size set to 4, my model should treat the 4 sequences as independant sequences.
So basically - Do the hidden states need to be initialized to 0 after every batch or after every sequence inside a batch? Doesnt matter if I or pytorch does it, but is it necessary?